# Does self-reference in JavaScript's Object cause poor performance?

Tags: javascript, object, self-reference

Does self-reference in JavaScript's Object cause performance problem?

```
var o = {
    name:"object"
};
o.obj = o;
```

And the final result is showed as follows:

[image]

we can see that object `o` is infinite with property of itself,and I want to know whether it causes performance problems.

Comment: Why would it? when doing what?

Comment: That infinite recursion is just a visual interpretation of a single pointer to itself. It does not exists as a real tree :)

Comment: Be careful if you want to serialize such objects.

Answer (score 0):

It might prevent `o` from ever being garbage collected, so if you had millions of them that might cause a problem as your computer ran out of memory.

It wouldn't however directly cause "poor performance", not by itself.

Comment: Self-referencing objects (or even two objects referencing each other) should be garbage collected correctly by Javascript.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I thought it probably would, subject to how smart the GC is.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-jsmemory/